# Label outliers in an scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, statistics, analytics, linear-regression

I've plot this graphic to identify graphically high-leverage points in my linear model.
[image]

Given the variable "NOMBRES" of the data set which my model uses, I've tried to plot all the points of my graphic but it gets illegible. Here's the code I ran:

```
> plot(hatvalues(tmodel),residuals(tmodel))
> text(hatvalues(tmodel),residuals(tmodel),labels=DSET$NOMBRES)
```

So I would like to plot just the points with leverage(hat value) above 0.05 using the label "DSET$NOMBRES".

Comment: `outliers <- which[hatvalues(tmodel)>0.05]; text(hatvalues(tmodel)[outliers], residuals(tmodel)[outliers], labels=DSET$NOMBRES[outliers])`

Comment: @BenBolker Post as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Identify high-leverage points according to your definition:

```
hlev <- which(hatvalues(tmodel)>0.05)
```

Add numeric labels to the graph:

```
text(hatvalues(tmodel)[hlev], residuals(tmodel)[hlev], 
   labels=DSET$NOMBRES[hlev])
```